# PHP | Why does the code error when I only change class name?

Tags: php, class

I have this class within PHP:

```
class Post{

    public function postUser($userData){

        $collection = $collection = (new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017'))->mydb->users;
        $insertOneResult = $collection->insertOne([
            "username" => $userData->username,
            "email" => $userData->email,
            "password"=>$userData->password,
            "level"=>$userData->level,
            "domainArray"=>array()
        ]);
    }

    


}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $test = new Post();
    $test->postUser($data);
}
else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}
```

Everything works as it should, but I want to change the class name. So I changed it to the following:

```
class PostUser{

    public function postUser($userData){

        $collection = $collection = (new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017'))->mydb->users;
        $insertOneResult = $collection->insertOne([
            "username" => $userData->username,
            "email" => $userData->email,
            "password"=>$userData->password,
            "level"=>$userData->level,
            "domainArray"=>array()
        ]);
    }

    


}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $test = new PostUser();
    $test->postUser($data);
}
else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}
```

When I do a post request with the second piece of code I get a 500 server error which indicates my code does not work anymore (on the first piece of code I get a 200 OK and everything works as it should) and then it does not work.
It has no dependencies from or to other classes which could error so I really do not have a clue where it goes wrong?
Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check your server logs

Comment: Should I turn error reporting on in Postman or in visual code?

Comment: Whatever server is reporting the 500 error

Comment: Yeah postman has 4 log files, but cant seem to find anything related to the error in them

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with my code right?

Comment: Is Postman _throwing_ a 500 error, or is it telling you that the server it is talking to is returning a 500 error. If the former, we can’t help you, you’d have to contact Postman. But it is probably the latter.

Comment: The last one, but I do not think it is a problem on the postman side since if I change the class back to the original name everything works again.

Comment: On your PHP server, that’s where you need to debug the logs with full error reporting turned in.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php refer to "Old-style constructors" for some insight as to why this may be happening. i.e. it's only an issue if your class is not in a namespace and your PHP version is less than 8.0 (otherwise I don't know what is happening)

Comment: @apokryfos, good catch! To the OP, you can see the warning [here](https://3v4l.org/kvfEk).

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name to something like **PostUserAction**
and don't forget to change
$test = new PostUserAction();

Or change method name to postUserMethod and it should work

```
class foo {
    function foo ($something){
        echo "I see ".$something." argument";
    }
}
```

It consider at as constructur for this class